# Resizing QDialog after removing QWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2, window-resize, qdialog

Is there any way by which I can resize a QDialog after removing a QWidget from its layout?
I'm still a beginner so bear with me if the code looks a bit silly.
The main dialog geometry is stored during the resizeEvent()

Before creating the widget:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ50a.jpg

When the widget is created:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eywME.jpg

When the widget is removed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRywl.jpg

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.resizeEvent(self, event)
    window = self.window()
    self.dialog_rect = window.geometry()
    self.DialogSizeChanged.emit() # pylint: disable=E1101
```

Here's the "create widget" code:

```
def create_info_widget(self):
    px = self.dialog_rect.x()
    py = self.dialog_rect.y()
    w = self.dialog_rect.width()
    h = self.dialog_rect.height()
    
    self.dialog_stored_rect = self.dialog_rect
    self.info_wdg = abw.ThumbnailInfo("Asset Info")
    self.asset_wdg_layout.addWidget(self.info_wdg)
    
    data = self.list_wdg.get_list_thumbnails_data()
    path = data['thumbnail']
    self.info_wdg.set_info_thumbnail(path)
    
    wdg_h = self.info_wdg.height()
    self.setGeometry(px, py, w, h + wdg_h)
    self.updateGeometry()
```

And the "remove widget" code:

```
def remove_info_widget(self):
    wdg = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QFrame, "Asset Info")
    if wdg:
        self.asset_wdg_layout.removeWidget(wdg)
        wdg.deleteLater()
        self.info_wdg = None

    self.setGeometry(self.dialog_stored_rect)
    self.updateGeometry()
```

As shown on grabbed images, when the widget is removed, it doesn't get back to its size before it was created.

Thank you,
Jacques.

Comment: did you try `resize` method

Comment: Thank you Rahul. Yes I tried but nothing seems to work so I eventually put the Widget in a QSplitter and set its size to 0 when I want to hide that Widget. Not perfect but at least it doesn't resize the QDialog.

Jacques.

Answer (score 0):

We will first resize it and then use `adjustSize` to let `QApplication` know.
We are using `resize` for just resizing, not for fixed values

**Make sure not to apply this when maximized**

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout
)


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout(self))

        self.add = QPushButton(self, text="Toggle")
        self.added = QPushButton(self, text="Hello There")
        self.added.setMinimumHeight(600)
        self.added.setVisible(False)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.add)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.added)

        self.add.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.added.setVisible(not self.added.isVisible())
        )
        self.add.clicked.connect(self.toggle)

        # trick is to use resize and self.adjustSize

    def toggle(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            return ...
        self.resize(self.width(), 600 if self.added.isVisible() else 100)
        self.adjustSize()


sample = QApplication([])

test = Test()
test.show()

sample.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul.
I had tried this before too but didn't use it because I couldn't find a way to keep the "main" Widget size when adding/removing a widget to it.
The adjustSize will resize it to fit the contents. If you change for instance the width of your "main" Widget and click on "Toggle" button, it will resize everything which is not expected.  

The idea for me was to get the geometry() of the dialog before the widget is added and that geometry restored when the widget is removed. 

Jacques.

Comment: Then resizing the window is a bad idea, considering it could affect the size of other layouts or widgets, maybe if another solution exists we may not face problem while shrinking, but it could affect widgets while expanding. or you could try setting the `fixed` size for the maindialog

Comment: Thank you Rahul but not allowing users to change the QDialog size is not an option for me.

Jacques.